How to ensure a MutationObserver is registered before expected changes in an iframe occur, so it can detect them? Is that even possible?
I want to be able to observe mutations in an iframe (from the parent document), so that when a certain element loads in there, I can take further actions. I haven't been able to get a MutationObserver detecting any mutations. After many attempts, I am assuming that perhaps my problem is somehow related with timing, hence the title/question.
Preliminary assumptions:

Parent document and iframe are Same Origin.
I control when to add the iframe to the DOM.
I control when to trigger the populating of the iframe.
When I trigger the population of the iframe (again, same origin), the MutationObserver should already be registered and ready so that it's able to observe the mutations that will happen in the iframe and invoke callback as expected.

Update: Additional info
The site on which I am working is not mine, it's a 3rd party. Clicking on certain link, the page loads a layer from which I want to get some element. I successfully get it to load in an iframe that I append to the same DOM. It takes up to 3 or 4 seconds to fully load (there are lots of things like images and so forth), but the element that I want loads way before that. I could use iframe.onload, which does work fine, and get the element, but I need to save time, several seconds is too long.

After several attempts, I have not been able to achieve that, despite having read several related answers in this forum, many of them being quite old (even > 10 years). Thus, I can't tell if what I'm trying to achieve is possible at all as of mid 2024 (perhaps there's a better way? or new bugs?, etc).
Here is a simplified version of the case. I guess either I am missing something extremely basic or extremely subtle, or MutationObserver can't be used with iframes in this way, and if so, please could anyone explain why:
Instructions:

In Chrome(ium) or Firefox, browse to https://example.com and open the developer tools.
Paste the following code in the console (or in a new snippet if in Chrome family) and run it.

I would expect changes being detected by the observer, but it detects nothing:
const setObserver = (iframe, sel) => {
    // Create a MutationObserver instance that observes the
    // documentElement of the passed <iframe> element.
    // Return the observer.
    const observer = new MutationObserver(
        (mutations, obsvr) => {
            // observer.disconnect(); // TODO when it works
            console.log(mutations);
            document.body.prepend("Mutation triggered!");
        }
    );
    observer.observe(
        iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        }
    );
    return observer;
};

const creaIframeInDom = () => {
    // Create an <iframe> and prepend it to the parent DOM.
    // Return the <iframe> element.
    const ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.id = 'myIframe';
    ifr.classList.add('my-class');
    ifr.name = 'myIframe';
    document.body.prepend(ifr);
    return ifr;
};

const creaAElemInDom = () => {
    // Create an <a> element linking to example.com, and prepend it to DOM.
    // Return the <a> element.
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'https://example.com';
    a.textContent = 'This is the trigger link';
    a.classList.add('trigger');
    document.body.prepend(a);
    return a;
};

const creaAElemInIframe = () => {
    // Create an <a> element with class="Link" and prepend it to the
    // iframe's body.
    // Return the <a> element.
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#';
    a.textContent = 'This is the EXPECTED element';
    a.classList.add('Link');
    if (iframe.contentDocument?.body.prepend(a)) {
      return a;
    }
    return null;
};

// This selects the element that we'll be waiting to observe when it
// loads inside the iframe, later:
const selector = 'a.Link';

// Create a test iframe in the DOM
const iframe = creaIframeInDom();

// Set a load event listener:
iframe.onload = function() {
    console.log('IFRAME HAS FIRED THE LOAD EVENT!!!!');
    console.log('readyState: ' + iframe.contentDocument.readyState);
    console.log(
        'iframe body\'s child nodes: ',
        iframe.contentDocument.body.childNodes
    );
};

// Set the observer
const myObserver = setObserver(iframe, selector);

// Set our test link in the parent DOM:
const aElem = creaAElemInDom();

// ...and give it the iframe as target:
aElem.target = 'myIframe';

// Click the trigger link, to load the page in the iframe and
// hopefully see the MutationObserver reaction as it loads.
// Make it a macro-task, and delay it a bit in the hope that it executes
// after above: (NOTE: Times are completely arbitrary here)
setTimeout(() => {
    aElem.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent(
        'click', {bubbles: false}
      )
    );
  // A bit later, append an <a> element to iframe's <body>
  setTimeout(() => creaAElemInIframe(), 500);
  }, 1000
);


So: what is wrong there?
Update 2024-05-29
Thanks a lot for the very useful comments and the answers so far.
@traktor: that's a very good point and I'll have to see how can I replicate in a simple way my case. However, doing the same test in the site I am trying this, gives me the same results. It's not my site, it's a 3rd party site. When one clicks on certain link, then there is a dynamic thing that loads and I want to work on that. I successfully get it to load in an iframe that I append to the same DOM. It takes up to 3 or 4 seconds to load, but the element that I want loads way before that, that's why I wouldn't like to use iframe.onload (which does work fine), to see if I can save time. One more thing, could you elaborate on this: "its content window is 'restricted' and has no accessible document property (i.e. it's null)." I am not sure I follow, since I can inspect normally its content from console once it's loaded, including adding a link in it.
@woxxom: that's a very interesting idea, I have thought about that, but I am not sure how I will be able to register the observer there in time before the desired mutation occurs. That's important part of my initial question, I have attempted something like that before without success.
Finally, @David Bradshaw: It's very encouraging that you have been working successfully on somehow similar challenges, and that you haven't seen any obvious flaw in the code itself. I haven't had the time to work with your example and I look forward to it, it's very promising!

I doubt you can use example.com for testing this. Logging the iframe object after opening example.com in it, shows its content window is "restricted" and has no accessible document property (i.e. it's null). It would also not be from the same origin as test code. You could post two minimal HTML pages for readers to test using a localhost server. However I seriously doubt you could add a mutation observer to the IFRAME document and expect it to survive a change in the Iframe's window location. Do you have control over the source code of the (same origin) page being loaded?

I would add that running it on localhost might also cause this to break, Try running it on the actual IP address of the machine.

Try using iframe.contentWindow.MutationObserver which belongs to the observed document.

I use MutationObserver in my iframe-resizer library for the last decade and I can confirm it still works and your code looks basically right to me. You can see a working example here:
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/packages/child/index.js#L774
In my case I target the body element, rather than the documentElement, but I doubt that makes a difference.
The things I would try is making sure your not running this on localhost, as iframes get treated as cross-domain when you do that for some reason that I have never understood.
Next I am wondering if you’re allowed to setup a MutationObserver in the parent page and have it observe the child page. You might need to move this code into a JS file that you load into iframe and then call that function.
